# PHP - Why is "Index.php?action=" not recognized as "Index.php?"

Tags: php, interpreter

All,

I'm building a front controller in PHP.  In it, I say:

```
if (isset($_GET['action'])){
        $action=$_GET['action'];
    } else {
        $action='';
    }
```

I follow that with a switch statement than governs which controller is called based on the value of `$action`:

```
switch ($action){
        case '':
            require_once('Controller_Welcome.php');
            $command=new controller_Welcome();
            break;
        case 'logon':
            require_once('Controller_Logon.php');
            $command=new controller_Logon();
            break;
        default:
            require_once('Controller_Unknown.php');
            $command=new controller_Unknown();
            break;
    }
$command->execute();
```

This works fine.  When I launch the app, the URL is `http://.../Index.php?` and the `Controller_Welcome.php` is called.  If I click on the logon menu entry, I get `http://.../Index.php?action=logon`, and the `Controller_Logon.php` is called.  If I manually edit the URL to set `...?action=...` to some unknown value, I get `Controller_Unknown.php`, which is my error page.  So all is well.

What I don't understand is that if I manually alter the url to show `http://.../Index.php?action=`, I get the error page rather than the welcome page.  Why is it that php doesn't associate a url ending with `...?action=` with the switch case `$action='';`?

(There's no logical user case when that would happen, but I still don't understand it...)

Thanks,

JDelage

PS:  Var_dumping `$action` returns `string(0) ""`.

Comment: var_dump($action); returns what?

Comment: Try var_dumping your variable, maybe it's not what you think it is.

Comment: don't see why welcome does not work, add an exit('') on this page for each statement instead of calling the controller in case there is an issue there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set `?action=`, you will get a `null` return value for `$_GET['action']`. So in your scenario, the switch statement will use the default case. Like everyone said, you can always use var_dump to see the return value.

Comment: 1) GET and POST values can never be `null`, at worst they're an empty string! 2) `null == ''`

Comment: switch doesn't do type checking, it's the equivalent of `if (null == '') {...}` which evalutes to true in a regular non-typed comparison in php.

Answer (score 2):

Just a note that may help with readability, and further development efforts. It appears your naming convention could permit a bit more "*magic*", giving way for a sort of convention over configuration, and avoidance of code duplication:

```
define('PATH_CONTROLLERS', 'path/to/controllers/');

$action = !empty($_GET['action'])
    ? $_GET['action']
    : 'default';

switch($action){
    case 'default':
    case 'welcome':
    case 'authenticate':
        $controller_name = "controller_{$action}";
        break;
    default:
        $controller_name = 'controller_404';
        break;
}

require PATH_CONTROLLERS . "{$controller_name}.php";
$controller = new $controller_name();

$controller->execute();
```

Given:

```
// index.php

$action:          'default'
$controller_name: 'controller_default'
require():        'path/to/controllers/controller_default.php'

// index.php?action=authenticate

$action:          'authenticate'
$controller_name: 'controller_authenticate'
require():        'path/to/controllers/controller_authenticate.php'

// index.php?action=foobar

$action:          'foobar'
$controller_name: 'controller_404'
require():        'path/to/controllers/controller_404.php'
```

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel - *Nested* ternary operators would issue a parse error if I had my way, but are you suggesting this is in fact *less* readable?

Comment: I am talking not of parse errors but of readability. `if` statement can always be read as plain English while ternary is barbarian. `$action = !empty($_GET['action']` my foot! most deceiving code one may writ

Comment: Haha @Col. Shrapnel - My mention of parse errors was only because *nested* ternary operators are so unreadable, they *should* in fact issue one, inhibiting coders from considering them an option. Circumstances like this however, I feel benefit from the brevity afforded by them. Six of one, really; any savvy programmer will (*should*) read them the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I think action is not what you think it is. This works as expected for me.

```
for url ending in 'action=' blank is echoed
for url ending in 'action=anything' anything is echoed


    var_dump($_GET);
    $action = $_GET['action'];

switch ($action){
        case '':
            echo "blank";
            break;
        default:
            echo $action;
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Saw your latest comment about dumping the var. I copied your code in verbatim and your switch statement works fine for me. Is there any way your `Controller_Welcome` is somehow erroring and then redirecting to the `Controller_Unknown`?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you describe cannot be reproduced. I used the following and the results do no demonstrate what you are describing:

```
<pre>
<?php

if (isset($_GET['action'])){
    $action=$_GET['action'];
} else {
    $action='';
}

var_dump($action);
echo "\n";
var_dump($_GET);
echo "\n";


switch ($action){
    case '':
        die('empty action</pre>');
    case 'logon':
        die('logon action</pre>');
    default:
        die('unknown action</pre>');
    }
?>
```

call:

```
http://host.com/test.php?action=
```

result:

```
string(0) ""

array(1) {
  ["action"]=>
  string(0) ""
}

empty action
```

Comment: you're a bit late with your answer

Comment: Reading the answers (and their times) I see what you mean ;)

Answer (score -1):

There is something with your other code.
this one works fine and throws Controller_Welcome at empty action